# WordPress Site showing "Content-Length: " At top of Page

Tags: wordpress

A WordPress based site of a friend (http://www.ipnrakeback.com/)  has a minor issue, it is printing out "Content-Length" near the top of the page.  It's mega ugly and my friend has asked me to help remove it.

I've no idea where to even begin to look.  Has anyone else ever had/solved this problem?

Thank you SO!

Comment: Maybe search for "content-length" in the code base?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the chunked encoding, but the utility I used doesn't show me the chunks.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I never saw these comments.  

I did do a search and nothing at all is coming up.  It's quite odd.  Neil, what utility are you using, if you don't mind my asking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered updating WordPress to the latest version?

Have you checked the theme files (especially header.php) to see if there are any print or echo statements lurking around that are printing this out.

e.g.

```
<?php print 'Content Length: '.ob_get_length(); ?>
```

Have you disabled all active plugins to check to see if it is one of these that might be causing the content length to be output?

Comment: Hi Chris!

Thanks for the response.  Somehow I didn't see this!

I have checked the theme files but haven't disabled all active plugins because the site is live (and not my site to be messing around with, as I'm just trying to help a friend out).  I suppose I could backup the whole site, plugins and all, and debug.

I'm not too familiar with WP but I guess that can't be overly difficult!

Thanks Chris!